# Chrome Omnibox extension to post form data to a website?

Tags: search, post, google-chrome-extension

How can an Omnibox extension create and post form data to a website and then display the result?

Here's an example of what I want to do. When you type `lookup bieber` into the Omnibox, I want my extension to post form data looking like

```
searchtype: all
searchterm: bieber
searchcount: 20
```

to the URL `http://lookup.com/search`

So that the browser will end up loading `http://lookup.com/search` with the results of the search.

This would be trivial if I could send the data in a GET, but lookup.com expects an HTTP POST. The only way I can think of is to inject a form into the current page and then submit it, but (a) that only works if there *is* a current page, and (b) it doesn't seem to work anyway (maybe permissions need to be set).

Before going off down that route, I figured that somebody else must at least have tried to do this before. Have you?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using the omnibox api:

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputChanged.addListener(
  function(text, suggest) {
    doYourLogic...
  });
```

Once you have you extension 'activated' due to a certain keyword you typed you can call something like this:

```
var q = the params you wish to pass
var url = "http://yourSite.com";

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("POST", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
 req.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (req.readyState == 4) {
    callback(req.responseXML);
  }
}
req.send(q);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it leaves out the crucial final step. In the callback, I want to actually display the search results page in the browser. Perhaps I could create a new tab, inject the HTML into it, and use the history API to set the URL to http://yourSite.com? That seems a bit tortuous, if not impossible.